# How can I get songs by album name or album spotify id?

Tags: echonest

As you may know EchoNest does not have album information. But, can I get songs by album name or album spotify id?.

Does anybody have a workarround for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Spotify ID for the Album, why don't you use the Spotify API to get the Spotify ID for each of the tracks (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-album/) - this gives an array of simplified track info as part of the response.

Then use the EchoNest track/profile api (http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html#profile) to get the information for each track?

*Update*:  Spotify is deprecating the echonest api (http://developer.echonest.com/) - but they're folding a good amount of the functionality into their own API.  In this case you can call https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-several-audio-features/ to get the audio info for up to 100 tracks at a time, this should reduce to 2 calls per album (one to get the track list and one to get the audio features).

Comment: Because I only have 20 request allowed per minute.